# Angular Favorite button added but color is not changing

Tags: angular, favicon, favorites

I have added favorite icon in angular but the color is not changing and when I refresh it is not showing as favorite

**Favourite.component.html**

```html
<button class="favouri" (click)="isFavoritee(x.ad_Id)">
    <i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-heart' : isFavorite , 'fa-heart-o': !isFavorite }"></i>
</button>
```

**favourite.component.ts**

```js
isFavoritee(elem: any) {
    this.toggle = !this.toggle;
    this.favouritedata = [];
    const favo = {
        'login_Id': this.localservice.getLoginId() ? this.localservice.getLoginId() : '',
        'ad_id' : elem ? elem : '',
        'category_Id' : 27,
        'mode': 'INSERT'
    };

    this.authservice.post('/api/Favourite/insert', favo).subscribe(data1 => {
        this.favouritedata = data1;
        console.log(this.favouritedata);
    }, error => {
        alert('something went wrong');
    });
}
```

Comment: what happens if you console log elem?  Also, you are not setting the values for isFavorite - I would add this in your isFavoritee function

Answer (score 0):

You are toggling a variable `toggle` in your component while your `ngClass` condition is checking for `isFavorite`. You will also need to use an array since you have multiple products that can be set as favorite.

You need to set `isFavorite` according to the id passed

```js
isFavorite: boolean[] = [];

isFavoritee(elem: any) {
    this.isFavorite[elem] = !this.isFavorite[elem];
    // Add other code here
}
```

Then in your template, update the `ngClass` condition.

```html
<button class="favouri" (click)="isFavoritee(x.ad_Id)">
    <i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-heart' : isFavorite[x.ad_Id], 'fa-heart-o': !isFavorite[x.ad_Id] }"></i>
</button>
```

As for why it is not showing the data when you refresh, since you are sending a POST request to save the favorite data, you should also have a GET request to get the same. You need to call this request in your `ngOnInit` and set `isFavorite` according to the response received from the API.

Comment: where should i add

Comment: isFavoritee(elem: any) {
    this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
    this.favouritedata = [];
    const favo = {
      'login_Id': this.localservice.getLoginId() ? this.localservice.getLoginId() : '',
      'ad_id' : elem ? elem : '',
      'category_Id' : 27,
      'mode': 'INSERT'
    };
    this.authservice.post('/api/Favourite/insert', favo).subscribe(data1 => {
      this.favouritedata = data1;
      console.log(this.favouritedata);
    }, error => {
      alert('something went wrong');
    });
  }

Comment: after i added, it is selecting for all products.

Comment: ngOnInit() {
    this.getForRentData();
  }   What should i add in  ngOnInit

Comment: I was not aware you have multiple products in your component. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: You need to get the favourite data from your API on `ngOnInit`

Comment: after adding the new code it getting error like Cannot create property '416' on boolean 'true'.  isFavorite i made like isFavorite: boolean = true;  in ngOnInit() { this.isFavoritee(this.isFavorite); }. It is correct or wrong

Comment: isFavorite is no longer a boolean but an array of `boolean`, see my answer for the new type of `isFavorite`

Comment: Still it is showing like these. Cannot read property '425' of undefined. I will add all TS code. You will get know what is the error

Comment: import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LocalstorageServiceService } from '../../services/localstorage-service.service';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

Comment: export class ForrentothermachineComponent implements OnInit {
  RentData: any = [];
  isSpinner:boolean = false;
  // tslint:disable-next-line: no-inferrable-types
  visibleHide: boolean = true;
  objectdata: any ;
  p: number = 1;
  favouritedata: any = [];
  isFavorite: boolean[];

Comment: constructor(private localservice: LocalstorageServiceService, private authservice: AuthService, private toastr: ToastrService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getForRentData();
  }

Comment: getForRentData() {
    this.RentData = [];
    this.isSpinner = true;
   const obj = {
 'category_Id' : 27,
 'subCategory_Id': 2,
 'lastDate' : '',
'dataCount': 0,
'mode': 'GET'
  };
this.authservice.post('/api/AdPost/get', obj).subscribe(data => {
 console.log(data);
        this.RentData = data;
        console.log(this.RentData);
        this.isSpinner = false;
      }, error => {
        alert('No Data Found');
      this.toastr.error('No Data Found');
      this.isSpinner = false;
      });
  }

Comment: sendRentdetails(elem: any) {
    this.objectdata = elem;
    this.visibleHide = false;
  }

Comment: isFavoritee(elem: any) {
    this.isFavorite[elem] = !this.isFavorite[elem];
    this.favouritedata = [];
    const favo = {
      'login_Id': this.localservice.getLoginId() ? this.localservice.getLoginId() : '',
      'ad_id' : elem ? elem : '',
      'category_Id' : 27,
      'mode': 'INSERT'
    };
    this.authservice.post('/api/Favourite/insert', favo).subscribe(data1 => {
      this.favouritedata = data1;
      console.log(this.favouritedata);
    }, error => {
      alert('something went wrong');
    });
  }

Comment: <button class="favouri" (click)="isFavoritee(x.ad_Id)"><i class="fa"
[ngClass]="{'fa-heart' : isFavorite[x.ad_Id], 'fa-heart-o': !isFavorite[x.ad_Id] }"></i></button>

Comment: Please help me regarding the problem

Comment: You just have to initialize the array `isFavorite: boolean[] = [];`. Please don't add your code in the comments, it's not easy to read. Instead, maybe we can continue the discussion through chat. (https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198944/angular-discussion-for-question)

Comment: i am not able chat something it is telling like You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq. i  have initalized the array. Now is working. Some issue is arised. when i logout and login favourite color is gone, color is not displaying

Comment: If it is not related to this issue, I would suggest you open a new question for the it.

Comment: after logout and login, favourite color is gone. But for example previously product is already favorite but now it will show like unfavorite. Again if i click icon it will show like favorite added but in functionality it is unfavorite.

Comment: after logout and login, favourite color is gone. But for example previously product is already favorite but now it will show like unfavorite. Again if i click icon it will show like favorite added but in functionality it is unfavorite.

Comment: This is because you are not storing the data anywhere. As I already mentioned in my answer, you need to fetch the data again from the API in your component's `ngOnInit`. The value of `isFavorite` will not persist throughout the lifetime of your application. Once this component is destroyed, `isFavorite` will be destroyed as well. Please go through the Angular docs. If you have any issues while coding, you can always come to StackOverflow. But it would be too much to expect someone to tell you how to code your entire application especially via the comments.

Comment: If this answer helped you fix this particular problem, you can accept it(this also increases your reputation ;)) and maybe create a new question for the other issues you face. But please be specific in your question and as always, happy coding :)